# How do I make filters auto-refresh when cells are updated via the API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the following function running in Apps Script, however the `onEdit` function is only called via manual edits. It does not work when I edit the sheet using the API. Here is the function:

```
 /**
 * Automatically sorts the 8th column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 8;
  var startRow = 2;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1,sheet.getLastColumn()-startColumn+1);
  
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
}
```

Edit: A commenter suggested that this question may be similar to another question, see comment below. However that question is discussing the difference between two functions, neither of which solve my issue, this question is asking about a functionality that neither of those functions provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diference between onEdit or onChange trigger?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/diference-between-onedit-or-onchange-trigger)

Comment: Thanks for the response, a quote from there states "Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run.", so this would not work.

Comment: _Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run_ That's true, but it would not affect a time-driven trigger.

Comment: @Tedinoz would you be able to show me how to do that or link me to some documentation? Would you also know what the minimum time is for the trigger and if there is any downside to having it running frequently?

Comment: I figured it out, you just go into the Triggers settings in the App Scripting. I've set it to the minimum time of 1 minute, not exactly what I wanted. If anyone has the automatic solution, I am still interested.

Comment: I have done some testing, you actually are at risk of a massive error using the time-based trigger. My trigger ran, while the spreadsheet was updating, and the data was saved in the wrong row because the trigger was refreshing the filter at the same time. This is dangerous and will not work at all, unless I somehow pause or buffer the data input while the trigger is running, however this adds complexity and is not something that I want to do.

Comment: What is it that causes your data to be updated. In any event, this is always a risk with dynamic data. A common solution is to make a copy of the data and make any changes, etc to the copy. The original is always available for reference/ review/ control totals, etc.

Comment: The data in the spreadsheet is updated via text commands on public forum (Discord). The programme is a fantasy stock investing game. I'm not sure if I could use a copy of the data as the whole game is visible on a single spreadsheet for the players to see. I may be able to solve the issue by updating an entire row at a time, instead of individual cells within the row, I will have to try this.

Comment: Sorry, just read your reply. Use '@Tedinoz', etc otherwise we don't get notification of your  comment. The problem is (IMHO) that you are working on the live data;I'd rather leave that data untouched, and either  create a dynamic copy of the live data (maybe a query or filter), OR make a full copy of the live data on a second sheet The second sheet is the sheet that your users see. I'll look at giving you a simple example.

Comment: Have you searched/ researched on stackoverflow and webapps for questions referencing discord and google-sheets &/or google-sheets-api to see if any users have had the same issue and found solutions to their questions?

Comment: @Tedinoz I have done quite a bit of googling around this issue and did not find a solution. Someone was suggesting that using a pivot table function updates it, but that sounds too complex. I tried adding a new row as a way to trigger the filter refresh. I can't remember if that worked, it added other complexities.

Comment: How about the couple of github links; were they of any value? I know nothing about discord; whether the spreadsheet drives the game or vice versa, or both. So I'm reluctant  to offer any further suggestions from a position of ignorance.. But I can't believe that the your scenario is unique. You said _ I edit the sheet using the API._, is it too silly to suggest that you should run the sort from the API, after the edit..

Comment: @Tedinoz It looks like pygsheets may work, I will have to try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938274/sort-a-spread-sheet-via-gspread